# Use Liquid to reference field through 1-N relationship in Dynamics portal web page?

Tags: dynamics-crm, liquid, adxstudio-portals

I am working in Dynamics CRM Online with the customer self-service portal add-on and trying to use Liquid to go from the user object to the related external identity record(s) to get a field from those records.  Looking at the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/liquid-objects#entities) under the "attribute or relationship name" section it mentions that "You can also load any related entities by relationship schema name".  So, for example, if I want to go from user to external identity and get the username field, I am trying this on a test web page:

```
{{ user.adx_contact_externalidentity.adx_username }}
```

where `adx_contact_externalidentity` is the name for the 1-N relationship.  I am logged in so the user object is set, but I get nothing back from the code above. Is it possible to do this and I have the wrong Liquid syntax, or do I need to use the service page approach to query the external identity data and return it?

**EDIT:**
I also tried `{{ user.adx_contact_externalidentity.size }}` since it is a 1-N relationship and I'm expecting `adx_contact_externalidentity` would be an array.  The result of that is 1 so it is an array object and there's an item in the array.  I then tried to access a field on the item with this:

```
{{ user.adx_contact_externalidentity[0].adx_username }}
```

but that didn't give me anything either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are heading in the right direction. On Adxstudio I've just confirmed this works:

`{{ user.adx_contact_externalidentity[0].adx_username }}` .

Try setting up entity permissions for the external identity record. This isnt required in Adxstudio, but I think it may be in Microsoft Portals.

Also try using a [loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/tags#iteration-tags) to iterate over the contents.

```
{% for child_page in page.children %}

<a href="{{ child_page.url }}">{{ child_page.title }}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You're right, entity permissions are required for Microsoft Portals, I thought I had already set up them up but I'll double check it again.  Since you mentioned it, this behavior does seem like permissions issues.  I'll post back here when I have a chance to check it.

Comment: Ok, I checked entity permissions, sure enough, I didn't have read permissions on external identity with the proper web roles assigned.  Once I corrected that, the code you have there was working for me.  thianks!